# Axios Post with React-native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I was searching for a long time answer, but I didn`t.
I have a post method with Axios. Values from input doesnt pass to state.

```html
class LoginForm extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {firstName:'', lastName: '', number: ''};
  }
  render(){
    return (
        <View>
        <Item floatingLabel>
        <Label>Ваше имя</Label>
        <TextInput Value={this.state.firstName} onChangeText={(firstName) => this.setState({firstName})}/>
        </Item>
        <Item floatingLabel>
        <Label>Ваша фамилия</Label>
        <TextInput value={this.state.lastName} onChangeText={(lastName) => this.setState({lastName})}/>
        <Text>{this.state.firstName}</Text>
        </Item>
        <Item floatingLabel>
        <Label>Номер телефона</Label>
        <TextInput value={this.props.number} onChange={(number) => this.setState({number})}/>
        </Item>
        <Button block style={{marginTop:50}} 
        onPress={() => {
          let data ={
            firstname: this.state.firstName,
            lastname: this.state.lastName,
            number: this.state.number
          }
          axios.post('http://10.0.2.2:3000/user_add',data)
                  }}>
        <Text>Отправить</Text>
      </Button>
      </View>
    );
  }

    }

export default LoginForm;
```

and

```html
app.post('/user_add',function(req,res){
var firstname = req.body.firstname;
var lastname = req.body.lastname;
var number = req.body.number;
var values = [firstname,lastname,number];
console.log(values);
  
 connection.query('INSERT INTO users (firstname, lastname, number) VALUES (?)',[values],function(err){
     if(!err) {
         console.log("User added!")
         res.send(firstname,lastname,number);
     } else {
         console.log(err);
     }
 })
});
```

It works, but uncorrect. 
User adds, but without my values, it adds only '', '', ''
I tried to do some advices: added events, tried to put values in massives, but it doesn`t work. 
Result:
[add values to DataBase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HHCZD.png)

Answer (score 4):

I use:

```
import {TextInput} from 'react-native';

<TextInput
   editable={true}
   placeholder="Write here"
   onChangeText={text => this.setState({ inputText: text })}
   value={this.state.inputText}
/>
```

This works great for me.
Notice that you wrote "Value" with big V in the first TextInput with firstName.
change it to small letter, maybe it will help.

Comment: input is related to DOM while this question is related to react-native

Comment: Sorry didn't notice. fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

You should use TextInput like this:
`onChangeText={(firstName)=>this.setState({firstName})}`

and repeat the same for lastName and number

> Callback that is called when the text input's text changes. Changed text is passed as an argument to the callback handler.

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput#onchangetext

Comment: Can you `console.log(this.state)` inside `submitForm` or use react-dev-tools to check the state of the component before clicking on the submit button ?

Comment: it`s app on android and it makes this things harder

Comment: It still has reference to e.target.value which should not be there anymore

Comment: I changed e.target

Comment: I noticed two typos: 1- first TextInput prop: prop is value not Value 2- last TexInput prop: onChange should be onChangeText. Still not sure it will fix the problem